# Best way to implement similar methods of two different classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two classes (`A` and `B`) which implements the same interface (`I`) in C#. The interface have 5 methods to implement. Implementations of two of those methods are almost the same in both `A` and `B` except each implemetation uses a different variable. Here is the abstract layout of my classes.

```
class A : I
{
     Folder folder;
     void method()
     {
        //implementation uses ``folder``
     }

class B : I
{
     List list;
     void method()
     {
        //implementation uses ``list``
     }
}
```

Because the implementation of `Method` is the same (except the one parameter) I want to have implement `Method` only once. What is the best solution according of design patterns? one simple option is to define a third class which implements `Method`and takes one parameter (either `list` or `folder`) and then call it within the `Method` of `A` and `B`. Any other solution?

------------Edit---------------

I don't want my `Method` to get any extra parameter. Under such circumstances, isn't static util class a better option than defining an abstract class?

Comment: maybe use an abstract class instead of an interface?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a shared abstract base class which takes a `T` generic parameter and implements `I<T>`. That same `T` will be passed to `Method`, which will be implemented in the base class:

```
public interface I<T>
{
    void Method(T t);
}

public abstract class Base<T> : I<T>
{
            public Base(T t)
            {
                  this.param = t;
            }

            private readonly T param;
    public void Method()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public class A : Base<Folder>
{
          public A(Folder folder) : base(folder)
          { }
}

public class B : Base<List>
{
          public B(List list) : base(list)
          { }
}

public class Folder { }
public class List { }
```

Now, you can do:

```
static void Main()
{
    var a = new A(new Folder());
    a.Method();

    var b = new B(new File());
    b.Method();
}
```

Comment: thanks, however I don't want my ``method`` to get any extra parameter.

Comment: @H.Z I've edites the code. You can take the `T` param at construction time.

Comment: one more thing, can I also change some pat of my implementation logic in the base class depending on the type of ``T`` (e.g. if (T is Folder)))?

Comment: If you need to do that, you should start questioning the use of generics at all, and pursue a different path. What do you need to change based on `T`?

Comment: so what is the best option then ?

Comment: What do you actually want to do based on `T`?

Comment: I just realized some part of the logic differs based on the type of the parameter (whether it's a Folder or List). So the implementation of the ``Method`` is not exactly the same for both classes.

Comment: @H.Z Then keep the shared base and add another abstract method which both classes will have to implement with the part that differs.

Comment: Isn't static Util class a good option here? The differences in the implementation are a few lines but they're scattered through the implementation so I need to define multiple abstract method that both classes implements

Comment: @H.Z How will a static util help here? I can't help you further if I don't know the design and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an abstract class instead of an interface. Of course this class must be generic.

Second option is to extract method to "static utils" class and in both use this "utils". But this assumes that `list` and `folder` are instances of same interface.

In my opinion the first option is the best one.

Comment: could you have a look at the 'Edit' I just added to my original post?

Answer (score 0):

If the method's implementations differ only by a variable's type consider using [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern combined with a generic base class.

```
abstract class Base<T> : I
{
   public void method()
   {
       var items = GetItems();
       HandleItems(items);
   }

   protected abstract IEnumerable<T> GetItems();

   void HandleItems(IEnumerable<T> items)
   {
       // do something with a sequence
       foreach(var item in items) Console.WriteLine(item);
   }
}

class A : Base<FolderItem>
{
    Folder folder;

    protected overrides IEnumerable<FolderItem> GetItems() {return folder.Items;} 

}

class B : Base<ListItem>
{
    List list;

    protected overrides IEnumerable<ListItem> GetItems() {return list.Items;} 
}
```